# Upgrade to 14.04 from 13.10 Not Working

Tags: 14.04

When I press the upgrade button after Ubuntu shows the upgrade is available.

I enter my pass word and press authenticate and then the box goes away, but nothing happens after that point.

I am running on Wifi is this an issue?

John

Answer (score 0):

Being on Wifi could be an issue; however, I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 on my wifi. 
It did take a very long time (near an hour) to do the upgrade with most of the time spent in downloading the packages.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well. The issue seemed to be "The value for the SHELL variable was not found the `/etc/shells` file" while I was running `update-manager` from ksh. I then added `/usr/bin/ksh` to `/etc/shells` and it seems working.